# Issue when selecting all checkboxes

Tags: javascript

i have this code which permits me to check all the checkboxes at once.

The problem is that when i select "select all" checkbox, it selects all the others, but if i have selected before 2 other checkboxes, it selects all except those two checkboxes!

It doesn't work properly..

can you please give it a look?

the function:

```
function selectAll(x) {
for(var i=0,l=x.form.length; i<l; i++)
if(x.form[i].type == 'checkbox' && x.form[i].name != 'sAll')
x.form[i].checked=x.form[i].checked?false:true
}
```

the select all :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sAll" onclick="selectAll(this)" />
```

and all the other checkboxes in my page:

```
<input type='checkbox' size='40' name='active[$i] ' ' ";?> <?php if($rows['img_active'] == 1) { echo 'checked'; }  ?> <? if("checked"){ echo 'value="1"';} else{ echo 'value="0"';}?>
```

Comment: Please post your generated HTML as the PHP is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: What should happen if some are checked? Should all get checked or all get unchecked?

Comment: if some are checked, then if you press the button select all it should check them all, and if you deselect it, it should uncheck all!

Answer (score 2):

```
function selectAll(x) {
    var checked = x.checked;
    for (var i = 0, l = x.form.length; i < l; i++) {
        var elem = x.form[i];
        if (elem !== x && elem.type === "checkbox") {
            elem.checked = checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to make the `for` body a block, @Alb please try again.

Comment: @pimvdb yeah thanks for the edit, didn't see that one in there :) Also jsfiddle demo here http://jsfiddle.net/XZpur/

Answer (score 1):

This will put all checkboxes in the same state as the check-all checkbox.

```
x.form[i].checked = x.checked ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this code (which toggles the checked state):

```
x.form[i].checked=x.form[i].checked?false:true
```

to this (which just checks it if unchecked):

```
x.form[i].checked=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
x.form[i].checked=x.form[i].checked?false:true
```

toggles the state of a checkbox, so naturally, any that was checked, will get unchecked.

You want

```
x.form[i].checked = true;
```

instead.

EDIT: Do you want all the checkboxes to behave according to the state of the `sAll` checkBox?

```
x.form[i].checked = document.getElementsByName('sAll')[0].checked;
```

Comment: @Alb Then I don't understand. Is this what you want? (see EDIT)